# How to write nested query in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have got two table

1. usermaster
2. AreaMaster

my sql query is like this:

```
select * from tblArea  where areaid
not in (select areaid from
tblUserMaster)
```

please tell me how to write such nested query in linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = tblArea.Where(x => !tblUserMaster.Any(m => m.areaid == x));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in linq to sql, just primitive types can be done

Comment: i have checked and its not working. its generating exception when i try to use foreach on it: Could not format node 'New' for execution as SQL.

Comment: thanks! its work when i have written: var result = tblArea.Where(x => !tblUserMaster.Any(m => m.areaid == x.areaid));

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any good way you can do something like:

```
var tb1 = tblUserMaster.ToList();
var result = tblArea.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !tb1.Any(m => m.areaid == x));
```

but it's not a good way, It's better to write store procedure instead loading all data to client. may be someone can do this better but I think it can not be improved.

**AsEnumerable()** keyword moves from linq->sql to pure linq but it loads all data.

Comment: @Rajesh Rolen- DotNet Developer, yes with tblUserMaster.ToList().Any(m => m.areaid == x) works

Comment: Now its working when i have written: var tb1 = tblUserMaster.ToList();
var result = tblArea.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !tb1.Any(m => m.areaid == x.areaid));

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var result=from tblarea in db.TblArea
where
  !
    (from tblusermaster in db.TblUserMaster
    select new {
      tblusermaster.Areaid
    }).Contains(new { tblarea.Areaid })
select new {
  tblarea.Areaid,
  tblarea.Column1,
  tblarea.Column2
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting, I tried a working version of this one in my machine and it worked fine.