# Filtering data table for multiple values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, rowfilter

I have 2 datatables objdatatable1 and objdatatable2 .

I need to filter the data in objdatatable2 such that market_id in objdatatable2  should not be in objdatatable1.

I am even to open to linq which will filter the contacts on not in clause

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212317/how-to-write-nested-query-in-linq

Comment: This might help you to derive your answer

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copies to DataTable `dt` all rows from `objectdatatable2` which have values in the 'market_id' field which do not appear in a field of the same name in `objectdatatable1`.  In this edit the 'market_id' field is of type `string` in `objectdatatable2` and of type `int` in `objectdatatable1`.

```
// This creates an empty DataTable with the same structure as objdatatable2.
DataTable dt = objdatatable2.Clone();

var results = objdatatable2.AsEnumerable().Where(r2 => !objdatatable1.AsEnumerable().Any(r1 => (r2.Field<string>("market_id") == r1.Field<int>("market_id").ToString())));
// Copy results to the DataTable only if there are results.
if (results.Count() > 0) {
    dt = results.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: this filters . but how can i convert back to datatable . .CopyToDataTable() tells "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh In that case call [CopyToDataTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx). I updated my answer.

Comment: .CopyToDataTable() tells "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Is the _market_id_ field an `int` on both DataTables?  If not you'll have to change the `Field T`'s in my code.

Comment: @its int in  objdatatable1   and string in other . so i cast both of them to string . but now its giving error as unable to cast decimal to string . but there is no  decimal column in  objdatatable2. wats wrong?

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh OK, I updated for the differing data type of 'market_id'.  Not sure why you're seeing the unable to cast decimal error.  HTH.

Answer (score 2):

`objdatatable2.AsEnumerable().SkipWhile(dr2 => { return objdatatable1.AsEnumerable().Any(dr1 => { return (dr1.Field<String>("market_id ") == dr2.Field<String>("market_id ")); }) });`